# How to open pdf from local path with parameters using gf/gx like command?

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, pdf

I have a path name with page number in vim buffer and I want to open it using Sumatra PDF.

```
d:\drivers\instruction.pdf -page 40
```

Instruction above works fine using command line - cmd.exe and it opens file properly at the page 40. When I open it with `gx` command from GVim, file is opened, but page is not correct. (It is last opened page)
How to open PDF file so it will go to proper page?

My conf:
Windows 10. GVim 8.1, SumatraPDF

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your own mapping. Perhaps like this:

```
nnoremap gX :!SumatraPdf <C-r><C-l><CR>
```

The `<C-r><C-l>` copies the current line as parameters for SumatraPDF.

Important: The line must only contain the parameters for SumatraPDF.

See `:h c_CTRL-R_CTRL-L`